# Applying a filter transition for Chrome and an opacity transition for Firefox and IE

Tags: css

I have the following CSS:

```
[data-state='not-ready'] .foo {
    -webkit-filter: opacity(0%);
}

[data-state='transitioning'] .foo {
    -webkit-filter: opacity(100%);
    transition: -webkit-filter 100ms ease-in;
}
```

But Firefox and IE do not support `filter`.

I want to apply a straightforward `opacity` transition for Firefox and IE, while still using a `filter` transition for Chrome.

How can I do this?

Comment: Just use `opacity`...no need for a filter at all...

Comment: Yes, that is an option, but `filter` is more performant I believe.

Comment: Marginally but other than browser sniffing (which would be required)...I think it's the best option. You have to use `opacity` anyway, and disabling just for Chrome to replace with a `filter` seems like a lot of work for an unknown perfomance boost.

Comment: I tend to agree. However when conducting tests (admittedly 18 months ago) `filter` was *substantially* more performant than a raw `opacity` transition. `opacity` transitions seemed to be very CPU intensive.